# How to release memory from Sinatra App 

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

Tying to setup api with Sinatra App.

Each request is 15MB.  Every time I refresh the page it adds 15MB of memory.  How can I clear information after each request?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'active_record'
require 'mysql2'
require 'json'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(adapter: 'mysql2', host: '127.0.0.1', database: 'dev_app', username: 'root', password: 'root')

get '/people' do
  q = "select name, age from people;"
  people = client.query(q, :as => :json).map{|one| {one['name'] => one['age'].to_i}}
  return people.to_json
  people = nil
end
```

Comment: How do you *know* where the memory is going? How big are your JSON objects and your MySQL connections? Have you profiled your application? Is this a real-world performance problem because of memory constraints, or just an abstract concern?

Comment: Monitoring memory from Ruby PID.  I let it go till it reached 500+ MB.  JSON objects at the moment are @ 50K but will grow.  This is a problem for me because wanted to keep memory under 100MB max so I could run several instances in AWS.  As for profiling, trying to do that now but this is my first attempt with Sinatra so trying to figure out what I need to import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Profile, profile, profile

You have not identified what is actually consuming memory in your application. Therefore, your issue is undefined, and any "solutions" amount to floundering around in search of a potential answer.

#### Potential Answers

1. Memory growth is not inherently a problem unless you actually run out of it. If that isn't happening, leave it alone.
2. The mysql2 gem has some known memory issues. That may be applicable to your scenario.

   - https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/85
   - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-use-result.html
   - http://numbers.brighterplanet.com/2011/03/15/what-you-should-know-about-mysql2-memory-usage/
3. [Garbage collection](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/GC.html) doesn't happen just because a variable or literal goes out of scope. There are conditions which trigger garbage collection, but you shouldn't monkey around with it or patch your garbage collector unless you are truly memory constrained.

   - http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/tuning-the-garbage-collector-with-ruby-1-9-2/
   - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/GC.html#method-c-stat
4. Make sure you understand [scoping in Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Scopes%20and%20Binding) so that you know when objects should be out of scope. However, just because objects are out of scope doesn't mean they *will* be garbage-collected, just that they *can* be.

Comment: After researching, profiling and testing app does release memory correctly.  I did manually initiate GC since I am using Legacy style app.  Better safe than sorry.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this matters or not, but I am pretty sure that last line of your get '/people' block doesn't get called, cause of the explicit return you have

```
return people.to_json # this exits the block
people = nil #this never gets called.
```

Comment: This shouldn't matter, since *people* goes out of scope when the request ends, but it's certainly a logic bug that's worth pointing out.